# Mapping collections with LINQ

Tags: linq, functional-programming

I have a collection of objects to which I'd like to just add a new property. How do I do that with LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = from i in ObjectCollection select new {i.prop1, i.prop2, i.prop3, ..., newprop = newProperty}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can using pure LINQ. However, if you're doing this sort of thing a lot in your code you may be able to make this work with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to add the extra property? Or, put a different way, what do you intend to do with the property once you have it in your new IEnumerable source?

If you need it for data binding, I have a helper class that might help you.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing this helper class.